# Number of distinct probe sequences in linear probing

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

According to Cormen book,number of probe sequences possible in linear probing if hash function is given as

h(k,i) =( h' (k) + i) % m is m

if h'(k) = k modulo 5  and m = 10, then how can we have 10 distinct probe sequences?

Initial probe is decided by h'(k), so number of probe sequences should be limited by h'(k) and should be 5 right ?

Comment: How does `i` change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CLRS says:

> Given an ordinary hash function *h'*: *U* -> {0, 1, ... , *m* - 1}, which
>   we refer to as an ***auxiliary hash function***, the method of
>   ***linear probing*** uses the hash function
>
> *h(k, i) = (h'(k)+i)* mod *m*
>
> for *i* = 0,1, ..., *m*-1.

Cormen means *h'* to be [surjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function). Otherwise the following wouldn't be true.

> Because the initial probe determines the entire probe sequence, there are only *m* distinct probe sequences

Comment: While he certainly *means* that, the quoted text does not *say* this.

Comment: @Henry you are right, the wording is not exact in this case. Probably, even word *only* could be perceived differently.

Comment: The only way we can get m distinct probe sequences is when h'(k) is also k mod m right ? Sorry, I am not understanding this.

Comment: @RajeshR *h'* could be any hash function which results in the set {1, ..., *m*-1}. As of *k* mod *m*, it depends on the particular value of *m*, but yes, that could be so.

Comment: @RajeshR take a look at [this example](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse326/00wi/handouts/lecture16/sld015.htm)